# Hi guys I wrote the following code in solidity to implementing the single point crossover method

Tags: solidity, blockchain, arrays, smart-contract-wallets

When implementing the singlePoint function  the child's value is not returned ,I think there is an error in the method of calling the function getValue?
can anyone help me?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.4.26;
contract Genetic{               
uint len = parent1.length;
uint []   parent1;
uint  []   parent2 =new uint [](len);
function setValue() external{
    parent1=[1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0];
    parent2=[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1];
}
function getValue() public  view  returns (uint [] memory ,uint[] memory){
return  (parent1 , parent2);
}
function singlPoint() public view  returns (uint[]){
    //creat child with initial elements 
    uint[] memory  child  = new uint [](len);
    (uint[] memory father, )= getValue();
    ( ,uint[]  memory mother ) = getValue();
    uint  cop = len / 2;
    for ( uint i=0; i < cop ; i++){
         child[i] = father[i];
    }
    for(uint j =cop ; j <= len;j++){
             child[j] = mother[j];
         
    }   
                    
  return   (child); 
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getValue` is fine.

The problem should be that the state variable `len` is always `0`. Writing `uint len = parent1.length;` won't change the variable when `parent1` changes, and it will always be the value it was during the contract deployement. So you need to change `len` during `setValue`.

This is how I would do it:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.4.26;

contract Genetic{               
    uint public len;  // start at 0
    uint[] public parent1;
    uint[] public parent2;

    function setValue() external{
        parent1=[1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0];
        parent2=[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1];
        len = parent1.length;   // add this
    }

    function getValue() public  view  returns (uint [] memory ,uint[] memory){
        return  (parent1 , parent2);
    }

    function singlPoint() public view  returns (uint[] memory){
        //creat child with initial elements 
        uint[] memory  child  = new uint [](len);

        uint[] memory father = parent1;
        uint[] memory mother = parent2;

        uint  cop = len / 2;
        for (uint i=0; i < cop; i++){
            child[i] = father[i];
        }
        for(uint j =cop; j < len; j++){  // < and not <= here
            child[j] = mother[j];
        }   
                   
        return child; 
    }
}
```

Comment: 0xSanson  :Thank you very much, I am very grateful to you for correcting the error, thank God